# Switching between .MOV and .WEBM video formats without checking for browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, safari, html5-video

Is it possible to provide to an HTML5 video tag two sources and let the browser (Chrome and Safari) decide which one to pick automatically, if the sources in question are:

- a .MOV file with transparency readable by Safari, but not by Chrome
- a .WEBM file with transparency (that is not applied by Safari)
  ?

At the moment if I put the .MOV file first Chrome tries to play it, ignoring the second .WEBM source. And if the .WEBM file is the first one, Safari plays it without transparency.

I don't know what type attribute to specify to make the fallback work. For example: `type="video/mov"` is not accepted by web standards and `type="video/mp4"` for the .MOV makes Chrome think it can play it.

I would like to avoid checking for the browser with javascript if possible.

Comment: Why avoid checking the browser? It's just simple 1 liners for checking each browser. Your complication is that both browsers can play the formats you provided, thus if you have conditions on which browser plays which format, then you have to use `IF` in your code...

Comment: Because I'm not well versed in video, video formats and codecs, and maybe I was missing something very basic that would have allowed to exploit native browser capabilities without sniffing the user agent, that is usually not the greatest idea

Comment: OK. I don't have a Mac or iOS (for Safari testing)... What video codec are using in your MOV? One idea is to check if the codec is supported by the browser, and then fallback to WebM if not supported.

Comment: Hi, you need to confirm the video codec used inside the MOV. Download a tool like **MediaInfo** or a player like **VLC**, if not sure what you've got... The codec check (using HTML5's  `canPlay` function) is an alternative to browser checking. It can't be done without knowing the codec.